# Where to ask how to start with stuff related to programming?

Tags: discussion, questions

that is my question. I was in Stack Overflow and I asked: `How to start with ReactJS?`, then 4 downvotes comes up and the question was put on hold for this reason:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Daniel A. White, Dave Newton, Streppel, Mat, Randy Morris yesterday
>   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
>   If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

so I said Ok, I saw another question which was like: `How to start with Node.js` and also was closed.

In my question I was asking also for references like tutorials, blogs or books related to React. But my question just wasn't accepted.

A lot of people thinks: go and Google it. Obviously that's the 1st thing we do, but what about if you reach with 1000 resources that Google provides you ? there are some very bad resources and others are good, so you want to know the people's opinions, you want to know what resources are good and bad and that's it.

So, where should I asked that type of questions?

Comment: "Primarily Opinion Based" is a poor close reason since there's a much more accurate one, but questions that ask for recommendations of books, libraries or off site resources are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related from Meta.SE: [Are "point me in the right direction" questions acceptable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226103)  |  [Where can I ask a "how to get started" question on a Stack Exchange site with regard to tech?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121705)

Comment: If you really want there to be SE sites where people can ask for recommendations, go support the [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation) and [Book Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation) proposals on Area 51 and the [Software Recommendations](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) site in Beta (check their guidelines!).

Comment: @sphanley I think "opinion based" is quite fitting reason for "what would be the best learning style for *me*" type of question. Yes one can consider it as "book recommendation", but what if the asker learns the best by trying or watching video or talking to friend?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that's fair, it would depend how the question is emphasized. It's definitely off-topic one way or the other, though.

Comment: why the downvotes ???!!! I am asking a question. COME ON!

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Voting is different on meta. But in any case, you are expected to do your research before asking. A bit of research would've shown you that we have an off-topic reason that explicitly says "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."... so people probably downvote you for that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Such a question isn't technically off topic in chat, but then again they may or may not feel like actually answering such a question, depending on what room you ask in and who's there at the time.

A question like that isn't on topic on any of the main sites.